# Refreshing a power query by VBA in a protected worksheet

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a protected excel worksheet with a power query that I want to refresh with VBA. My code should unprotect the sheet, refresh the query then re-protect the sheet.
The basic script is very simple (I have tried it with specific named queries but I get the same result)

```
Sub refresh()
Worksheets("Sheet2").unprotect
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Worksheets("Sheet2").protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End Sub
```

This results with a message saying I'm trying to update a protected cell.
However, if I run the following:

```
Sub refresh()
Worksheets("Sheet2").unprotect
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

it works but obviously doesn't re-protect the cells once the refresh has been completed.
How can I get the script to re-protect at the end of the sub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the macro continuing before the query completes

What happens if you right-click the query, go to properties, uncheck [ ] enable background refresh?

[image]